# Image path return null in Android

Tags: android

I want to get image path and upload to the server. 
Here i successfully read image from gallery and set into image view but image path return null.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                    // Get the url from data
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                        // Get the path from the Uri
                        String path = getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(), selectedImageUri);
                        Log.i(TAG, "IMAGE" + path);
                        Log.d("INFO", selectedImageUri.toString());
                        // Set the image in ImageView
                        profilepicture.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* Get the real path from the URI */
        public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Image path return null in Android`. No. Not at all. Wrong subject. getRealPathFromURI() returns a null.

Comment: `want to get image path`. From what? You did not tell  where you get the 'image' from. Or that intent.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `getRealPathFromURI()`, as it is not going to work reliably.

Instead, use your favorite image-loading library (e.g., Picasso, Glide) to load the image from the `Uri`.

Or, in a worst-case scenario, use `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, then pass that stream to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. Just do this I/O on a background thread, please (which image-loading libraries will handle for you, among other benefits).

Answer (score 0):

Update your method getRealPathFromURI:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            if (imagePath == null) {
                File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "New");
                if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                        Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                File file;
                String path = "img_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
                file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + path);

                imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = null;
                try {
                    parcelFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver()
                            .openFileDescriptor(contentUri, "r");
                    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                    saveBitmapToPath(image, imagePath);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return imagePath;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
String path = yourAndroidURI.toString() // "/mnt/sdcard/FileName.mp3"
File file = new File(new URI(path));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

**Use this function to convert String URL to Bitmap**

```
public Bitmap getImage(String url) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new 
            URL(url).openStream(), BUFFER_IO_SIZE);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(baos, 
            BUFFER_IO_SIZE);
            copy(bis, bos);
            bos.flush();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baos.toByteArray(), 0, 
            baos.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "loadImageFromArrayList: IMAGE DOWNLOAD FAILED!" +e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: it reply bitmap as you pass URL